# Why is the inverse of this function not a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

[image]

[image]

Why does $F^{-1}$ need to be defined on all of $Y$? I can have this function: $g(x)=x,\quad x\ne 3$ and even though it is not defined for all $x$ in its domain, it is still a function, right?

Comment: It's a function on F(X) (the range of F), but not on Y.  A function assigns a value to every point in its domain.

Comment: So does that mean g(x) is not a function because it doesn't assign a value to every point in its domain? Or is x=3 just not a part of its domain?

Comment: It can be a function, as long as you specify a valid domain.  g(x) is a function on the set of all real numbers which are not 3, but it is not a function on all of the real numbers until you specify its value at x=3

Comment: Think of a function as being a pair of things, a rule AND a domain where the rule is valid.

Comment: What is property (1) by the way?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have no idea. I think the author is referencing another chapter that I haven't studied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $g$ is not a function defined on $\mathbb R$, but only a function defined on $\mathbb R\setminus\{3\}$ (or to the same effect a *partial* function on $\mathbb R$).
So in the problem statement, $F^{-1}$ is a function $F(X)\to X$, but not a function $Y\to X$.

Answer (score 1):

For $F:X\rightarrow Y$ to be a function, by definition, it has to map every element of $X$ to an element of $Y$.  To use your example, $g(x)=x,\,x\neq3$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}-\{3\}$ but not on $\mathbb{R}$ since it does not assign a  value to $3\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the inverse $F^{-1}\subset Y\times X$ of a *relation* $F\subset X\times Y$ by setting $$F^{-1}:=\{(y,x)|(x,y)\in F\}$$ Relation $F$ is a *function* if and only if for each $x\in X$ there is a unique $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in F$. The defined $F^{-1}$ will also have that property if and only if $F$ is a *bijective* function. In that case function $F^{-1}$ will also be bijective.